# How do you calculate the total amount of each loop that's being read in a foreach loop?

Tags: c#, winforms, loops, foreach, logic

I've got a DataGridView that has 2 columns - product name and the quantity of it.  So I grab each row in a foreach loop and calculate the price of it.  I managed to do that but I can't seems to figure out how to store ALL the calculated rows into a single variable and insert them into a database.

This is what I have so far:

```
string cMedication = string.Empty;
string cQuantity = string.Empty;
string cAppointment = string.Empty;
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in this.dataPrescription.Rows)
{
    cMedication = row.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
    cQuantity = row.Cells[1].Value.ToString();
    cAppointment = txtAppointmentID.Text;

    if (cAppointment == "NO APPOINTMENT HAS BEEN MADE")
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please make an appointment first at the Nurse counter", "WARNING");
    }
    else
    {
        //this.savePrescription(cMedication, cQuantity, cAppointment);

        string strConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["HConnection"].ConnectionString;
        string strCalc = "SELECT medicationPrice FROM MEDICATION WHERE medicationName= ('" + cMedication + "')";

        using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(strConnectionString))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmdCalc = new SqlCommand(strCalc, connection))
            {

                connection.Open();

                SqlDataReader readPrice = cmdCalc.ExecuteReader();
                if (readPrice.Read())
                {
                    string getPrice = readPrice["medicationPrice"].ToString();
                    double doublePrice = Convert.ToDouble(getPrice);
                    double doubleQuantity = Convert.ToDouble(cQuantity);

                    double result = doublePrice * doubleQuantity;
                    string answer = result.ToString();

                    //insert TOTAL amount to database below

                }

                readPrice.Close();
                connection.Close();
            }
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: why not use a hashtable or an array?

Comment: Consider using a SqlParameter instead of `WHERE medicationName= ('" + cMedication + "')"` because you are accepting `cMedication` as an input value this is prone to SQL injection attacks.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up, Pete.  Do you have any suggestion on how I should solve my problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you're doing this kind of thing a lot then I would use some kind of ORM like Entity Framework (or write your own).  Then you would just load / create entites and save them.

If that's overkill for what you're doing then you could build up an insert statement and execute it, much like you've done to query the medication price.  Only as I've mentioned in the comment, use SqlParameters instead of string concatenation to avoid possible sql injection attacks.

Something like this (untested).

```
var builder = new StringBuilder("INSERT INTO MedicationLine (MedicationName, Quantity, Price) VALUES ");
int i = 0;
var parameters = new List<SqlParameter>();

foreach (DataGridViewRow row in this.dataPrescription.Rows)
{
    string cAppointment = txtAppointmentID.Text;

    if (cAppointment == "NO APPOINTMENT HAS BEEN MADE")
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Please make an appointment first at the Nurse counter", "WARNING");
        return;
    }

    string cMedication = row.Cells[0].Value.ToString();
    string cQuantity = row.Cells[1].Value.ToString();

    i++;

    string strConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["HConnection"].ConnectionString;
    string strCalc = "SELECT medicationPrice FROM MEDICATION WHERE medicationName = @medicationName";

    using (SqlConnection connection = new SqlConnection(strConnectionString))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmdCalc = new SqlCommand(strCalc, connection))
        {
            command.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("medicationName", cMedication);
            connection.Open();

            SqlDataReader readPrice = cmdCalc.ExecuteReader();

            if (readPrice.Read())
            {
                string getPrice = readPrice["medicationPrice"].ToString();
                double doublePrice = Convert.ToDouble(getPrice);
                double doubleQuantity = Convert.ToDouble(cQuantity);

                builder.AppendLine();
                builder.Append("(";
                builder.Append("@Name");
                builder.Append(i);
                builder.Append("@Qty");
                builder.Append(i);
                builder.Append("@Price");
                builder.Append(i);
                builder.Append("),";

                parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("Name" + i.ToString(), medicationName);
                parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("Qty" + i.ToString(), doubleQuantity);
                parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("Price" + i.ToString(), doublePrice);
            }

            readPrice.Close();
            connection.Close();
        }
    }
}
```

The idea is to end up with something like:

```
INSERT INTO MedicationLine (MedicationName, Quantity, Price) VALUES
    (@Name1, @Qty1, @Price1),
    (@Name2, @Qty2, @Price2),
    (@Name3, @Qty3, @Price3),
    ...
```

Then execute it.  Don't forget to trim the trailing comma.

```
using (var connection = new SqlConnection(strConnectionString))
{
    using (var command = new SqlCommand(builder.ToString().TrimEnd(','), connection))
    {
        command.Parameters.AddRange(parameters.ToArray());
        connection.Open();

        int recordsAffected = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

**Disclaimer
Syntax may be wrong as done without an IDE!